# Alternative way (quicker) of looking into a probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, problem-solving

In a book called *Applied Statistics and Probability for Engineers (Fourth edition)* by Douglas C. Montgomery and George C. Runger there is a problem that reads: "A lot of 100 semiconductor chips contains 20 that are defective. Two are selected randomly, without replacement, from the lot.

(a) What is the probability that the first one selected is defective ?

(b) What is the probability that the second one is defective given that the first one was defective ?

(c) What is the probability that both are defective ?

**My solution**

Let the set $ A $ be the one that contains all the 100 semiconductor chips and $ B $ the set that contains all the chips except the one we selected firstly.
The sample space of our experiment is:

$$ S = A \ \times B = \{(x,y):x \in A \ \land y \in B\}$$ 
The number of possible outcomes is
$$ |S|=|A|\cdot|B|=100 \cdot 99=9900 $$

For question (a): Let $ C $ be the set of the defective semiconductor chips that are defective. The event of interest is:

$$ K = \{(x,y)\in S:x\in C \ \land y\in B \}=C \times B $$
The probability of $ K $ is (assuming uniform probability measure):
$$ \Bbb P(K)=\frac{|K|}{|S|}=\frac{|C| \cdot|B|}{|A| \cdot |B|}=\frac {|C|}{|A|}=0.2 $$
For question (b):
Let $ U $ be the set that contains all the elements of S where the second selected item is defective. The probability of interest is:
$$ \Bbb P(U|K)= \frac{\Bbb P(U \cap K)}{\Bbb P(K)} $$
We know $ \Bbb P(K) $ but we don't know the value of the numerator which asks us to find the the probability that both choices are defective. That probability is just:
$$ \Bbb P(U\cap K)=\frac{|20| \cdot |19|}{9900} $$
Finally, we get:
$$ \Bbb P(U|K) = 0.19 $$
For part (c): We found in part (b) that $ \Bbb P(U \cap K)= 0.038 $

**Questions**

First of all, the problem asks us to find the joint probability of $ U $ and $ K $ after question (b) which asks for the conditional probability of $ U $ given $K $. The thing is that, in order to calculate that probability we need to find the probability of the $ \Bbb P (U \cap K) $ as stated in the solution. I feel that there is a reason the authors asked the questions in this specific order. So, Is there a way of calculating $ \Bbb P (U|K) $ without knowing $ \Bbb P(U \cap K)$ ?

Secondly, I always approach probability problems by defining sets and working with their cardinalities. This method is safe but slow (not good for exams). Are there any faster methods ?

Thank you in advance for comments / answers.

Comment: I think you are thinking to hard.  $20$ defective out of $100$ means any given one has $\frac {10}{100}$ prob of being defective. Given that first was defective there are now $19$ defiective out of $99$ so prob is $\frac {19}{99}$.  Now it's just a matter of convincing ourselve for c) we can multiply prob both are defect is $P(first def)*P(second def|first def)=\frac {20}{100}\frac {19}{99}$.  which... we can probably talk ourselves into believing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it was really helpful!

Comment: Take a look at chapter 3 of this book: https://archive.org/details/XQUHIUXHIQUHIQXUIHX2 or https://www-biba.inrialpes.fr/Jaynes/prob.html It solves many problems of this kind giving you a lot of logical and intuitive insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it.

a) Any chip is equally likely to be selected, so the probability of choosing a defective one is $${20\over100}$$ the number of defective chips divided by the total number of chips.

b) Imagine that a defective chip has been chosen.  Then there are $19$ defective chips and $99$ total chips remaining, so the conditional probability is $${19\over99}$$ for the same reason as in part a).

c) The probability that both are defective is the product of the probabilities in parts a) and b) or $${20\cdot19\over100\cdot99}$$  As a a check this is the same answer we would get if we divided the ${20\choose2}$ ways to choose two defective chips by the ${100\choose2}$ way to choose two chips, which is the way I would do part c) if parts a) and b) hadn't been asked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was really helpful. Your approach on (b) and (c) was perfect. On the first question tho you assumed that the number of all possible outcomes is 100 which gives the correct result. But our experiment is that we take 2 balls out of 100 balls which gives a much bigger sample space (According to my calculations 9900 possible outcomes!). Why does those to approaches give the same answer ? (I can see that $ |Β| $ sets cancel out in my original question but i can't get it intuitively). Thank you.

Comment: @AndreasMastronikolis The question in part a) is what is the probability that the first ball selected is defective, so it suffices to consider the experiment of drawing the first ball.  The outcome is decided before the second ball is drawn.